# Reading open layers javascript file

Tags: javascript

How to read this line of code? It is miniature file code.

Trying to debug an issue with open layers so debugging ol.js file

```
this.jc=null===a?void 0:Ek(this.Kb)
```

Comment: Do you know what [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is?

Comment: if (a === null){
 jc = undefined
} else {
  jc =Ek(this.Kb)
}